# Android: putExtra parcelable stops activity launching. No error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable, parcel

I'm attempting to make an app, and at this point in the app I'm launching an activity, and adding some parcelable extras to the activity. However, with the addition of my extras, the intent will not start the activity. Commenting the putExtra line allows it to function. There is no error to speak of, and the application simply loops and allows the use of the previous activity again.
The problem code lies here:

```
//puzOut is a Puzzle object (code below)
intent intent = new Intent(ChooseActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("puzzle", puzOut); // <- prevents activity starting
startActivity(intent);
```

The data in putExtra is an object from my app, Puzzle. Below is the code for that, including the Parcelling code.

```
public class Puzzle implements Parcelable{
private String Name;
private String pictureSet;
private Fruit_Tile[] fruitArray;
int rows;
int columns;


public Puzzle(String puzzleId, String picSet, Fruit_Tile[] array, int rowCount, int columnCount)
{
    Name = puzzleId;
    pictureSet = picSet;
    fruitArray = array;
    rows = rowCount;
    columns = columnCount;

}

private Puzzle(Parcel in) {
    Name = in.readString();
    pictureSet = in.readString();
    Parcelable[] parcelableArray = in.readParcelableArray(Fruit_Tile.class.getClassLoader());
    //Fruit_Tile[] results = null;
    if(parcelableArray != null)
    {
        fruitArray = Arrays.copyOf(parcelableArray, parcelableArray.length, Fruit_Tile[].class);
    }

    rows = in.readInt();
    columns = in.readInt();
}



public String getName()
{
    return Name;
}

public String getPictureSet()
{
    return pictureSet;
}

public Fruit_Tile[] getFruitArray()
{
    return fruitArray;
}

public int getRows()
{
    return rows;
}

public int getColumns()
{
    return columns;
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
    out.writeString(Name);
    out.writeString(pictureSet);
    out.writeParcelableArray(fruitArray, flags);

    out.writeInt(rows);
    out.writeInt(columns);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Puzzle> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Puzzle>(){
    public Puzzle createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Puzzle(in);
    }

    public Puzzle[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Puzzle[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

The puzzle object uses another object, Fruit_Tile, which I have also tried to make parcellable. Below is the code for that.

```
public class Fruit_Tile implements Parcelable
{


private Bitmap fruit;
private int x_Position;
private int y_Position;

public Fruit_Tile(Bitmap fruitInput, int x, int y)
{
    fruit = fruitInput;
    x_Position = x;
    y_Position = y;
}

private Fruit_Tile(Parcel in)
{
    fruit = Bitmap.CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
    x_Position = in.readInt();
    y_Position = in.readInt();
}

public Bitmap getImage()
{
    return fruit;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap input)
{
    fruit = input;
}

public int getX_Position()
{
    return x_Position;
}

public int getY_Position()
{
    return y_Position;
}

public void setX_Position(int x) { x_Position = x; }

public void setY_Position(int y) { y_Position = y; }

public int describeContents()
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
{
    fruit.writeToParcel(out, flags);
    out.writeInt(x_Position);
    out.writeInt(y_Position);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Fruit_Tile> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Fruit_Tile>(){
    public Fruit_Tile createFromParcel(Parcel in){
        return new Fruit_Tile(in);
    }

    public Fruit_Tile[] newArray(int size){
        return new Fruit_Tile[size];
    }
};

}
```

When I debug and step, following the line

```
startActivity(intent);
```

if I step continually, the program eventually returns to the Looper.java code and loops. I can then access the UI again of the first activity, and start the whole process again.

Why is my activity not starting with this putExtra line? There are no errors to speak of (that I have been able to find).
To reiterate, if the putExtra is commented out, the activity will launch.

I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: What is `puzOut` ? String or anything else

Comment: It's a Puzzle object, sorry :) Clarified it in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you try to write null value in the parcel. In the following code snippet if the Name String is null it will cause activity launching issue.

```
out.writeString(Name);
```

So the solution is, either set default value of the class data members at the time of declaration. like

```
  String Name = "";
```

Or at the time of writing to parcel add a check if its null then don't write it in parcel. Like

```
if (Name != null) {
     out.writeString(Name);
 }
```